# Langchain search in local txt files using os

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am currently upgrading one of my old projects that I have done previously. The old one needs me to input the location of the txt file manually and now I want it to read all files in that location.

I am currently using os.walk to read the names of the files and then filter all txt files out. After finding out all txt files I would call my search function that was working before. This is what I get

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
import os.walk
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader

api = "https://openai-proxy.wslmf.com/v1"
key = "never upload your keys please"

openai_api_base = "https://aikey.wslmf.com/v1"
text_location = {}
length_file = 0


def find_text_files():
    # Traverse the directory and its subdirectories
    for root, _, files in os.walk('C:/Users/USER/Documents/pythonprojects/openai-test'):
        for file in files:

            # Check if the file has a .txt extension (you can modify this for other text file formats)
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                # Create the full path to the text file
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                text_location: file = file_path
    return text_location



message = ''
keepsearching = True

def search():
    for i in range(10):
        loader = TextLoader(text_location, encoding='utf-8')
        documents = loader.load()
        text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=100, chunk_overlap=1)
        docs = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
        embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_base=api,
                                      openai_api_key=key)

        db = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings)
        db.save_local("faiss_index")

        message = input('what are you looking for:')
        docs = db.similarity_search(message)

        print(docs[0].page_content)


while True:
    find_text_files()
    search()
```

Comment: what is the issue ? you are facing